# error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘see_sum’ with no type [-fpermissive] see_sum(){cout<<sum;} Не могу найти ошибку

Tags: c++

```
class rahunok{
    public:
        int uniq_id;
        rahunok(int id, float sm, float pr){
            uniq_id  = id;
            sum      = sm;
            percents = pr;}
        see_sum(){cout<<sum;}
        new_perc(float addp){this->percents += addp;}
        new_sum(){this->sum+=(this->sum * (this->percents/100));}
    protected:
        float sum, percents;
};
```

Comment: Написано-же "русским" языком. Декларация функции без возвращаемого типа. Добавьте **void**.

Answer (score 1):

Если функция не возвращает ничего, то её необходимо явно объявить как void

```
class rahunok{
    public:
        int uniq_id;
        rahunok(int id, float sm, float pr){
            uniq_id  = id;
            sum      = sm;
            percents = pr;}
        void see_sum(){cout<<sum;}
        void new_perc(float addp){this->percents += addp;}
        void new_sum(){this->sum+=(this->sum * (this->percents/100));}
    protected:
        float sum, percents;
};
```